# Disk space after downloading from mega.co.nz less twice of file size

Tags: windows-xp, mega

After I download a file from MEGA it looks like the file is saved twice when saving to the destination folder.

For example, if I download a 700 MB file, it occupies 1400 MB of hard disk memory.

I tried finding this temporary file, and it seems nowhere to be found. How can I find the hidden file and delete it?

Tried it with both Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: Did you use Chrome?

Chrome keeps a copy in the internet cache as well as copying the downloaded file to the Downloads folder as well.

to remove the file, simply clear the cache in Settings, or manually remove the cached file from your User profile folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's downloaded twice, find any of the downloaded file names (the more unique the better) and perform a system wide search for it.

It *may* be useful to download [TreeSize by Jam](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/). It will review all your folders and 
files and show which folder(s) contains the most files (disk space).. This may still be laborious but may help you if there are other large folders you are not aware of.

Comment: TreeSize solved the problem, found the files and deleted them, thank you very much1 :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it! All the best! :-)

Comment: so where was the file?

Comment: In Documents and Settings, in Mozilla and Firefox file... I don't know how to explain it better, but you can spot it right away after TreeSize finishes scanning.

Comment: so it was a temp file, then CCleaner would have deleted this temp file ;-)

Comment: The problem is the temporary file does not have the actual file name. It's just a numeric name, such as "00000008" with no extension, stored in the browser's "File System" directory

Answer (score 5):

It downloads to "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\".

Comment: This is exactly where it goes, Chrome then copies it to the /%USER%/Downloads folder.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**

Click on the padlock in the address bar, click Cookies

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

Expand mega.nz item, select File Systems, click Remove and OK.

[image: Step 2]

Comment: This is the best and easiest answer, but I've found an even easier way: "Padlock > Site settings" will lead to a page where you will see the size of the data downloaded by Mega and you will be able to delete it from there.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest way:

1. When in the mega.co.nz website, click on the padlock icon next to the address and then click on "Site settings".
2. You will see a settings page informing of the amount of data downloaded by the website at the top of the page. Just click "Delete data".

[image: Padlock icon screenshot, borrowed from Colemar's answer]

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer here will work, there is a much more direct way to do this.

In Chrome, open settings and expand the advanced section.  Click the "content settings" button, then "all cookies and site data".  In the window that opens, search for mega.  Click the result and you should see a "file system" button.  Click that and it should show persistent storage taking up a large amount of space.  Click "remove" and you space will be freed.